# Merge date and time to datetime: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, merge, timespan

I'm new to MVC and I encountered a problem and already spent lots of time on it. Hope you could help me.

I want to combine [datetime]dateFrom and [timespan]timeFrom to [datetime]dtFrom. The reason I have to separate them is because I want to create date calender and time picker to pick up date and time.

Now I'm working with MS SQL Server and I can save dateFrom and timeFrom with no problem.

How can I merge dateFrom and timeFrom and save in dtFrom?

Here is my database entity.

```
[Table("DaylightSavingsDate")]
```

public class DaylightSavingsDate

```
{
    [Column("iTimeZoneId")]
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Timezone")]
    public virtual short TimeZoneId { get; set; }

    [Column("dtFrom")]
    public virtual DateTime? dtFrom { get; set; }

    [Column("dtTo")]
    public virtual DateTime? dtTo { get; set; }

    [Column("DateFrom")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime dateFrom { get; set; } 

    [Column("TimeFrom")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public virtual TimeSpan timeFrom { get; set; } 

    [Column("DateTo")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime dateTo { get; set; }    

    [Column("TimeTo")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public virtual TimeSpan timeTo { get; set; }

    public virtual STTimeZone Timezone { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the edit action in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "TimeZoneId,dtFrom,dtTo,dateFrom,dateTo,timeFrom,timeTo")] DaylightSavingsDate daylightsavingsdate)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var dateFrom = daylightsavingsdate.dateFrom;
            var timeFrom = daylightsavingsdate.timeFrom;
            var dtFrom = daylightsavingsdate.dtFrom;

            dtFrom = DateTime.Parse(dateFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") + (timeFrom.ToString("hh:mm:ss")));

            globalDb.Save(daylightsavingsdate);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.TimeZoneId = new SelectList(globalDb.TimeZones, "Id", "Name", daylightsavingsdate.TimeZoneId);
        return View(daylightsavingsdate);
    }
```

So I tried to parse dateFrom and timeFrom to DateTime to save in dtFrom but the error shows:
"Input string was not in a correct format."

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take parsing and formatting out of the picture if you can.  You already have a `DateTime` object and a `TimeSpan` object.  If the date was loaded without a time, then it's time is zero (midnight).  So just add the `TimeSpan` and you're done.

```
DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2014,1,1);
TimeSpan timeFrom = new TimeSpan(1,0,0);
DateTime dtFrom = dateFrom + timeFrom;

Console.WriteLine(dateFrom);
Console.WriteLine(timeFrom);
Console.WriteLine(dtFrom);
```

Output:

```
1/1/2014 12:00:00 AM
01:00:00
1/1/2014 1:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Aside - why are you building classes for feeding tables with time zone / daylight saving time data?  You should instead be using [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) or better yet - [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I can get 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 for dateFrom and 00:01:00 for timeFrom but I still can't merge them to 2014-01-01 00:01:00.

Comment: In the MS SQL server, I can merge them by: select CAST(dateFrom as DATETIME) + CAST(timeFrom as TIME) as dtFrom
from DaylightSavingsDate. But I don't know How to merge them and save as dtFrom in my MVC C# project?  I already tried add code in controller and save method but still can't work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The code is very clear.  Simply add the timespan to the datetime.  It works.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I've added dtFrom = dateFrom + timeFrom; in my code but they still not merge to dtFrom

Comment: Work for me.  See updated answer.  Not sure what you're doing differently.

Comment: could you tell me where should I add code in? Controller or edit.cshtml or Save(daylightsavingsdate) method?

Comment: I think all I need is to create a custom ASP.NET MVC Model Binder to join the two values back together as a single DateTime when the form is submitted.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that works for you, but again, I ***strongly*** urge you to look at using `TimeZoneInfo` or Noda Time rather than trying to manage your own daylight saving transition data in SQL Server.